# Can fetch but then can not find branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

This is the kind of occasional Git nuance that confounds me. Can someone explain what's going on here? I'm fetching from one repository (with redirect rules from config ignored) and pushing into another (with redirect rules from config applied):

```
$ HOME=/dev/null git fetch origin refs/heads/8.9.170
 * branch                  8.9.170    -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git push origin refs/heads/8.9.170
error: src refspec refs/heads/8.9.170 does not match any

$ git rev-parse refs/heads/8.9.170
refs/heads/8.9.170
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/heads/8.9.170': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/branch-heads/*:refs/branch-heads/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Meanwhile, fetching a branch/ref that doesn't exist would throw an obvious error:

```
$ HOME=/dev/null git fetch origin refs/heads/obviously/invalid
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/obviously/invalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Consider using:

```
git push origin FETCH_HEAD:refs/heads/8.9.170
```

See the long answer as to why.

#### Long(ish)

This part of your `.git/config` looks slightly odd, but not impossibly odd:

> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>     url = https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git
>     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>     fetch = +refs/branch-heads/*:refs/branch-heads/*
> ```

That second `fetch =` line seems at first blush unlikely to match anything: Git itself doesn't use the namespace `refs/branch-heads/` for anything.  If it matches nothing at all, that's fine; it's harmless.  If it does match something, it will force-update any `refs/branch-heads/` names that you fetch.  You are explicitly not fetching any, but at first, this seems like an odd thing to do.

But it turns out that `https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git` *does* have a whole bunch of `refs/branch-heads/` names in it (I checked with `git ls-remote` and saw them).  What they're for, I have no idea.  They also have the standard `refs/heads/` branch names.  Because they do have these `refs/branch-heads/` names, you should be extra-careful where I note that you can do a full `fetch` below.

Meanwhile, *this* output here:

> ```
> $ HOME=/dev/null git fetch origin refs/heads/8.9.170
>  * branch                  8.9.170    -> FETCH_HEAD
> ```

suggests that you have a truly ancient Git binary.  This plus a few other items are likely the sources of all your subsequent trouble.  Git versions since 1.8.4 would print:

```
$ HOME=/dev/null git fetch origin refs/heads/8.9.170
 * branch                  8.9.170    -> FETCH_HEAD
   <hash>..<hash>          8.9.170    -> origin/8.9.170
```

because modern Git will "opportunistically update" any fetched branch based on the `fetch =` settings, and while you have one nonstandard setting, that's preceded by the standard setting.  So you must have a severely outdated Git.  You *can* still get your work done with it though; you just need to be more explicit, by running:

```
HOME=/dev/null git fetch origin +refs/heads/8.9.170:refs/remotes/origin/8.9.170
```

which this time *will* update `refs/remotes/origin/8.9.170` (forcefully, because of the plus sign), or more simply:

```
HOME=/dev/null git fetch origin
```

which fetches everything and updates all names based on the `fetch =` lines.  Note that this will obey your extra rule for the `refs/branch-heads/` entities, updating all your remote-tracking names (`refs/remotes/origin/*`) and these weird names (whatever they are).

As it is, though, you're only dropping the new commit hash ID into the special `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file, where `git fetch` writes it so that `git pull` can figure out what just got fetched.  Since you're not *running* `git pull`, this is not much use to you.  But that's why we see the output that mentions `FETCH_HEAD`.

Now, we can move on to the `git push`, which you'll need to change.  You are using (and getting):

> ```
> $ git push origin refs/heads/8.9.170
> error: src refspec refs/heads/8.9.170 does not match any
> ```

You don't have a branch named `8.9.170`.  Even if you had a modern Git (instead of a pre-1.8.4 Git), you'd still not have a *branch* named `8.9.170`.  You would, instead, have a *remote-tracking name* named `8.9.170`.  You therefore have two options at this point:

1. Create a *branch* named 8.9.170.  Then, your command would work as-is.
2. Push from the name or hash ID that you do have.

For option 1, this works better if you have a modern Git that has created the remote-tracking name.  You can simply run `git switch 8.9.170` or `git checkout 8.9.170`, which will create that branch and then check it out.  Or, to avoid having to check it out (this takes a bit: the chromium source is big), you can run `git branch 8.9.170 origin/8.9.170`, which creates `8.9.170` from `origin/8.9.170`.  Lacking any of these, you can extract the commit hash ID from `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, or use the name `FETCH_HEAD`, to create that branch.

For option 2, which is simpler, you can just run this command:

```
git push origin FETCH_HEAD:refs/heads/8.9.170
```

which is the TL;DR at the front.  The name `FETCH_HEAD` refers (temporarily!) to the hash ID obtained by the `git fetch` that, because your Git is ancient, failed to create a remote-tracking name.  This temporary `FETCH_HEAD` storage lasts until the *next* `git fetch`, which overwrites it, so this has to be done pretty quickly.  (That's why this works fine for `git pull`, which just runs `git fetch`, then *immediately* runs a second Git command to use the values from `.git/FETCH_HEAD` *before* they can get replaced.)